# how to calculate the value of the index json android

Tags: java, android, json, adapter

this is my json variabel `ijiInvest,persenHmint1, inuNilai, selisih,persen_hke1, tanggal,ijiId` i want to get value `Result=inuNilai(i)-inuNilai(0)` and sending this value to my adapter, but i don't know the way to send it, for detail this is how i declare my variabel :

```
public class NabDetail {
    public static final char[] Perubahan1 = null;
    String ijiInvest, ijiId;
    String tanggal;
    double persenHmint1, inuNilai, selisih,persen_hke1;

    public NabDetail(String ijiInvest, double persenHmint1, double inuNilai, 
            double selisih,double persen_hke1, String tanggal,String ijiId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.ijiInvest = ijiInvest;
        this.persenHmint1 = persenHmint1;
        this.inuNilai = inuNilai;
        this.selisih = selisih;
        this.ijiId = ijiId;
        this.tanggal = tanggal;
        this.persen_hke1=persen_hke1;
    }

    public String getIjiInvest() {
        return ijiInvest;
    }

    public String getIjiId() {
        return ijiId;
    }

    public String getTanggal() {

        return tanggal;
    }

    public double getPersenHmint1() {
        return persenHmint1;
    }

    public double getInuNilai() {
        return inuNilai;
    }

    public double getSelisih() {
        return selisih;
    }

    public double getpersen_hke1(){
        return persen_hke1;
    }
}
```

this is how i parse my json :

```
try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
            NabDetail item = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

        item = new NabDetail(jsonObject.optString("lji_invest"), 
                        jsonObject.optDouble("persen_hmin1"), 
                        jsonObject.optDouble("lnu_nilai"), 
                        jsonObject.optDouble("selisih"), 
                        jsonObject.optDouble("persen_hke1"),
                        jsonObject.optString("tanggal"),
                        jsonObject.optString("lji_id") 
                        );


                listData.add(item);
            }

            TabelNABDetail adapter = new TabelNABDetail(NABActivityDetail.this, 
                    listData);
            listviewtabel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

this is how i inflate it in my adapter :

```
if(view==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tabel_detailnab, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.tanggal=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.vartanggal);
            holder.lnunilai=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varlnunilai);
            holder.selisih=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varSelisih);
            holder.persenHmint1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varpersen);
            holder.persen_hke1=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varlpersenke1);
            holder.perubahan=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.varperubahan);
            view.setTag(holder);
        }
        else{
            holder=(ViewHolder)view.getTag();

        }
        holder.tanggal.setText(listData.get(position).getTanggal());
        //convert double ke string
        holder.lnunilai.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getInuNilai()));
        holder.selisih.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getSelisih()));
        holder.persenHmint1.setText(String.format("%.5f",listData.get(position).getPersenHmint1())+"%");
        holder.persen_hke1.setText(String.format("%.5f",listData.get(position).getpersen_hke1())+"%");
//      holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).Perubahan1));
        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView tanggal, lnunilai,selisih,persenHmint1,persen_hke1,perubahan;
    }
```

the row that i comment `//       holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).Perubahan1));
            return view;` is a place for i put the Result value. but i don't know the way to calculate and send it into my adapter, i hope somebody understand what i mean and cab help to solve my problem, thank you verymuch.

Comment: What is `listData` ?
Does not `holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).Perubahan1-listData.get(0).Perubahan1));` work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my interpretation about your problem, you have an array of JSON data, and you want to calculate the **difference** (selisih) between the value of **inuNilai on Index 0** and **inuNilai on Index 1**, and insert it into the textView, is this correct?

If this is what you want to do, then you need to do this :

```
holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(listData.get(position).getInuNilai()-listData.get(position-1).getInuNilai());
```

for a clearer code :

```
double inuNilai0 = listData.get(position-1).getInuNilai();
double inuNilai1 = listData.get(position).getInuNilai();
double result = inuNilai1-inuNilai0;
holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(result);
```

But remember, do check that if position index = 0, the code might cause a `NullPointerException`. You have to check that if the index is 0, then result = 0

Maybe like this :

```
if (position==0) {
        holder.perubahan.setText("0");
} else {
        double inuNilai0 = listData.get(position-1).getInuNilai();
        double inuNilai1 = listData.get(position).getInuNilai();
        double result = inuNilai1-inuNilai0;
        holder.perubahan.setText(String.valueOf(result);
}
```

I hope this is helpful, good luck ^^

Comment: thank you for your answer.... this is so close to what i need, this is just change listData.get(position-1) into listData.get(0) if i want to take it from first index... GBU ^^